# Github release task fails with internal error

Tags: azure-devops

Trying to release to github using this devops task:
https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/GitHubReleaseV1

The run fails with:
2023-07-12T09:47:10.4783230Z ##[error]An unexpected error occurred while fetching the initial commit.

My scenario:
I have a repo in azure devops on which i run a pipeline to create some binaries. I have a private repo in Github i want to push the binaries to.

Is it failing because its a private repo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running with system.debug variable setting to 'true' I found the issue.

1. This repo is updated with code from a private ADO repo and the Commit Id's are not synced, hence it looked for a non-existing commit id
2. The repo was archived accidently - so github API was not reachable

Its working now :)